# How to model Additional EVM (TxEVM) with LTE waveform?

Tags: digital-communications, ofdm, lte, communication-standard

I would like mention my understanding in the following,

In an LTE OFDM signal assume,
**Nfft=8;
scs=15 kHz;
BW=5MHz;
Sampling Rate N=7.68 MHz;**
We are taking **1msec** of sample; Therefore total **sample =76800** sample.

I found a model from Mathworks which is explained on this   [link.](https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/measuring-lte-uplink-evm-and-in-band-emissions.html)

```
    txWaveform={76800} % Assume OFDM Signal in time doamin   
    txEVMpc = 1.2;            % Set desired transmit EVM in percent 
    gain = txEVMpc/(100*sqrt(double(info.Nfft))); % Compute gain of additive noise 
    evmModel = gain * complex(randn(size(txWaveform)), randn(size(txWaveform)))/2; 
    rxWaveform = txWaveform+evmModel;        % Add noise to the transmitted waveform
```

Now I have the following question,

1. In the code on line 3 the gain it depends on **Nfft** size (it is 8 in my example here). However, I can have some previous scaling on the **"txWavefrom"** (I can increase the signal amplitude). In that case **'evmmodel'** signal power remains constant but this should be adjusted!!! how?
2. If I do oversampling of **txWaveform**, how can I adjust the EVM **gain**?
3. Any link or tutorial on additional EVM modeling would help a lot.

Thank you.